# Sum of probabilities of all samples gives the total volume?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, mathematical-statistics, classification, expected-value

I am working on a churn problem (binary classification - whether a customer will churn or not). Now using logistic regression, I get the probability whether the customer will churn or not.
Can I add up these probabilities (rows are distinct per user) to get the total volume of predicted churn? (expected value of the total number of users that will churn)?

How would I prove this statistically?
$$ E(X) = \sum_{x=1}^{n} x_i P(x_i)$$
$$ where  \ X:churn\ volume,  x_i = 1 \ (1 \ for \ every \ user), P(x_i):probability \ from \ the \ classification \ model $$

1. Does this look right? Or what might be the right working?
2. Does the equations change when there is a class imbalance.
   Please correct me or point me in the right direction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have $n$ customers, for each customer $i$ you have the value $c_i$ telling us whether the customer churned ($c_i=1$) or not ($c_i=0$), and you have the belonging probabilities $p_i := p(c_i=1)$ and $1-p_i = p(c_i = 0)$. As always with binary random variables, the expectation $E[c_i]$ is $p_i$:
$$
E[c_i] = 0\cdot (1-p_i) + 1\cdot p_i = p_i.
$$

Now, you want to compute the expectation of the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i$. But the expectation operation is linear, thus:
$$
E[\sum_{i=1}^n c_i] = \sum_{i=1}^n E[c_i] = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i.
$$

Thus, in summary, you can indeed sum up all the probabilities to obtain the expected total amount of churning.

This result is independent of whether there is a class imbalance or not.

Comment: this makes a lot more sense. thanks for the detailed explanation.